# method of converting a static library into a dynamically linked library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, static-libraries, static-linking

If all I have of a library is a *.a static library.  Is there a way I can convert that to *.so dynamically linked library?  Maybe using ld?

I'm using SUSE Linux. ELF platform.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649735/how-to-link-static-library-into-dynamic-library-in-gcc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This command will attempt to do what you want:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,--whole-archive library.a -o library.so
```

But if your library wasn't compiled with `-fpic`/`-fPIC`, which it probably wasn't, it won't work (it might *appear* to work, but you don't get any of the benefits of shared libraries).

Comment: it's good to put `-Wl,-no-whole-archive` after the list of libraries you want to include in this way