# How to make a static/dynamic library that uses a library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I am making a C++ library. In the library, I am using some functions in another static library (e.g. ref.a).

I want to generate one library file, either mylib.a or mylib.so, so that any program using my library does not need to link to the static library (ref.a).
I got some ideas from others [how to link static lib into dynamic lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649735/how-to-link-static-library-into-dynamic-library-in-gcc), like "--whole-archive", but not so clear how to do it.

To get mylib.a, I just ar -rc mylib.a mylib.o ref.a (may not be a standard way).
What about a shared lib, e.g. mylib.so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To get mylib.a, I just ar -rc mylib.a mylib.o ref.a

No, that wouldn't work. You have to "expand" `ref.a` before you include it into mylib.a:

```
mkdir tmp.$$ && cd tmp.$$ && ar x ../ref.a &&
cd .. && ar rc mylib.a mylib.o tmp.$$/*.o &&
rm -rf tmp.$$
```

> What about a shared lib

That's simpler:

```
gcc -shared -o mylib.so mylib.o -Wl,--whole-archive ref.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

(It's *very* important to have the trailing `-Wl,--no-whole-archive`, or you may get nasty link errors from system libraries that the compiler driver adds to the end of the link.)