# GNU ld linker flag to see linked objects from a static library

Tags: linker, gnu, ld, flags

I am using CMake to build an executable binary for a Renesas processor using GNU toolchain. I changed from object to static libraries and had issues with the interrupt table being correctly linked. Thanks to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649735/how-to-link-static-library-into-dynamic-library-in-gcc) I found out about --whole-archive option.

My question is, is there a linker flag or way that shows me the objects that are linked from a library so that I know which objects (so these would be the objects without unresolved symbols) the linker is ignoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ld` can create a map file that will show which objects are linked and for what reason (i.e. which object requested the symbol to be resolved):

```
gcc -Wl,-Map -Wl,mapfile ...
```