# Symbols from a static library are not exported while linking to a shared library

Tags: c, cmake, clang

Code for a shared library is modular, consists of several independent units. Each unit is built into a static library.

---

unit1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void HelloWorld() {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

---

unit2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void GoodbyeWorld() {
  printf("Goodbye World!\n");
}
```

---

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)

add_library(unit1 STATIC unit1.c)
target_compile_options(unit1 PRIVATE -fPIC)

add_library(unit2 STATIC unit2.c)
target_compile_options(unit2 PRIVATE -fPIC)

add_library(merged SHARED)
target_link_libraries(merged unit1 unit2)
set_target_properties(merged PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
```

---

Build steps:

```
cmake . && cmake --build .
```

Exported symbols by libmerged.so:

```
$ nm -D --defined-only libmerged.so 
0000000000201020 B __bss_start
0000000000201020 D _edata
0000000000201028 B _end
00000000000005a0 T _fini
0000000000000458 T _init
```

**Q** Why symbols HelloWorld and GoodbyeWorld are not exported? How to fix it?

- I've tried `--version-script` without success.

  Additional setting in CMakeLists.txt

  ```
  set_target_properties(merged PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS -Wl,--version- 
  script=merged.version)
  ```

  ---

  merged.version

  ```
  merged {
    global: HelloWorld; GoodbyeWorld;
    local: *;
  };
  ```
- Also tried force load static libaries without success

  ```
  set_target_properties(merged PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS -Wl,-force_load,libunit1.a)
  ```

Comment: What is about [--whole-achive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649735/how-to-link-static-library-into-dynamic-library-in-gcc)?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. The option is `--whole-archive`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks. `-Wl,-whole-archive libunit1.a libunit2.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive` solves my issue. Now thinking how to do it in CMakeLists.txt, so `-Wl,--no-whole-archive` is appended to a linker command, not prefixed.

Comment: Just google for e.g. `cmake "--whole-archive"`. There are many questions on Stack Overflow on this topic. (But none of them contains ideal solution).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pass the `--whole-archive` option to the linker.
In CMake, you can do it as follows.

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)

add_library(unit1 STATIC unit1.c)
target_compile_options(unit1 PRIVATE -fPIC)

add_library(unit2 STATIC unit2.c)
target_compile_options(unit2 PRIVATE -fPIC)

add_library(merged SHARED)
set_target_properties(merged PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
target_link_libraries(merged
        "-Wl,--whole-archive libunit1.a libunit2.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive"
        unit1 unit2
)
```

Note: The `target_link_libraries` command can be used to specify linker flags as well, not only library names. The quotes are important, otherwise CMake might rearrange the flags and remove duplicates.

#### Exported symbols

```
$ nm libmerged.so | grep " T "
000000000000065d T GoodbyeWorld
000000000000064a T HelloWorld
0000000000000670 T _fini
0000000000000520 T _init
```

---

Another option, to avoid the problem, would be to create **`OBJECT`** instead of **`STATIC`** libraries for `unit1` and `unit2`.

#### CMakeLists.txt

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)

add_library(unit1 OBJECT unit1.c)
target_compile_options(unit1 PRIVATE -fPIC)

add_library(unit2 OBJECT unit2.c)
target_compile_options(unit2 PRIVATE -fPIC)

add_library(merged SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:unit1> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:unit2>)
set_target_properties(merged PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
```